# How can I reach that the camera opens automatically in Ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework

Hey at the moment my camera opens with a click event "takePhoto". So I first have to press a button before the camera opens and I actually can take pictures. But I want the camera to open when I select the camera tab, so when I open the camera page. Is there anything like a "when open page event" so my camera opens automatically?

```
export class PostPage {
  public photos: any;
  public base64Image: string;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private camera: Camera) {

  }
  ngOnInit(){
    this.photos = [];
  }

  ionViewDidEnter(){
   const options: CameraOptions = {
  quality: 50,
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
}


this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
 // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
 // If it's base64:
 this.base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
  this.photos.push(this.base64Image);
  this.photos.reverse();

}, (err) => {
 // Handle error
});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you can use [**Lifecycle events**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/)

For example **ionViewWillEnter** (*Runs when the page is about to enter and become the active page.*) or **ionViewDidEnter** (*Runs when the page has fully entered and is now the active page. This event will fire, whether it was the first load or a cached page.*)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public _navCtrl: NavController,
              private _camera: Camera) {
  }

  ionViewDidEnter(){
    this._camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
    let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
    }, (err) => {
     // Handle error
     });
  }

}
```

Comment: so can I just add this ionViedDidEnter in line 11 and delete the button in the html code? (I have the ionViedDidEnter where I had the "take photo function before or do I have it to put it exactly there where you have put it.

Comment: Yes you can. It that case camera will be activated automatically without the need for another button. You an call as many functions as you want inside ionViewDidEnter. I was put that above only as an example.